# Как растянуть ячейку в таблице

Tags: html, css

Есть таблица, в ней 3 столбца, в левом текст по левому краю, в правом текст по правому краю а между ними пустой столбец, в котором border-ом прочерчена линия, или пунктир, как мне ее сделать видимой без строгого указания размера? Длина текста ведь может быть разной.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/xxcxc71z/

Comment: soledar10, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


table{
  width: 100%;  
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td:first-child,
td:last-child{
  white-space: nowrap;
}
td:first-child{
  text-align: left;  
}
td:last-child{
  text-align: right;
}
td:nth-child(2){
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Левый текст</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>Правый текст</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```